# Enable Disable keys using C Program

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

I need to disable the task keys for both Linux and windows using a C program . I tried using the `windows.h` but as the name states it is not working for the Linux and in case of windows also its not working properly . I tried to do this using the `GetAsyncKeyState` function but still have no clues to Linux key handling.  As I am new to system code I have referred to following but unable to get through the issue.

So please suggest some solution that could be helpful in handling keys (Enable/Disable) on both platforms (Linux/Windows) ?

And is it okay to use key-scan codes and ASCII codes for the Key event handling?

I have already referred to :

[Disable task switching keys with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134998/disable-task-switching-keys-with-c)

[Disable keyboard keys when the console of c Run using c or c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407257/disable-keyboard-keys-when-the-console-of-c-run-using-c-or-c)

[How to handle key press events in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501014/how-to-handle-key-press-events-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for low level, cross platform keyboard handling then you might want to have a look at libsdl - http://www.libsdl.org/. The keyboard handling section is - http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryKeyboard